'Who to makes' - is this phrase correct?

The “trade unionists” that run Previ control Vale’s Administrative
Council, where people like Sergio Rosa decide who to makes up the
board and what investments it makes. source
It is of course hardly a revelation to say that the history of
capitalism has been simultaneously a history of appallingly violent
battles over who to makes the rules of the game, from the local
and individual level to the global. source

Are these phrases correct, or are they just typos?

I do not see the phrase in the second link. In any case, have you ever seen in English: "who to [verb]"? This boils down to editing. relative clauses do not take "to" after the relativizer.

They are just typos. English grammar requires a finite verb (as "who makes...") in this situation.

Thank you, you've bean of great help!

Typos  or translation errors, at least for the first one.

"bean" is also a typo, or eggcorn.
